# Typescript and Node js getting a "Not a Function Error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, typescript

I have an error in possibly my synatx for a forgot password feature I am creating.

The error I get is this

```
[TypeError: self._forgotPasswordRouteHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function]
```

My route looks like the below

```
getRoute(): hapi.IRouteConfiguration {
        const self = this;
        return {
            method: 'POST',
            path: this._config.apiPrefix + 'forgotpassword',
            handler: function(request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) {
                let parsedRequest: IForgotPasswordDataRequest = null;
                let uuid: string;
                const result = new Promise<string>(function(resolve, reject) {
                    self._validator.validate(request.payload, ForgotPasswordDataRequestValidator)
                        .then(function(validationResult) {
                            if (validationResult.error) {
                                resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidRequest));
                                throw null;
                            }
                            parsedRequest = <IForgotPasswordDataRequest> request.payload;
                            return self._forgotPasswordQueries.createEmailResetToken(parsedRequest.email);
                        }
                        , function(error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidRequest));
                            throw null;
                        })
                        .then(function(newUuid: string) {
                            uuid = newUuid;
                            return self._peopleQueries.getPersonByEmail(parsedRequest.email);
                        })
                        .then(function(person: IPersonModel) {
                            resolve(responseHelper.getSuccessResponse(null, null));
                            self._forgotPasswordRouteHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail(uuid, parsedRequest.email, person.name_to_call_user);
                        })
                        .catch(function(error: any) {
                            console.error(error);
                            resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.unknownError));
                        });
                });
                reply(result);
            }
        };
```

And in my forgotPasswordHelper.ts file I have a function like this

```
sendPasswordResetEmail(person: any): Promise<void> {
    const token = person.forgot_password_token.dataValues.forgot_password_tokens_id;
    const data: IForgotPasswordEmailEmailData = {
        'resetUrl': this._config.websiteUrl + 'reset_password/confirm/' + token,
        'emailTo': person.contact_detail.value,
        'name': person.person.name_to_call_user
    }
    return this._emailHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail(data);
}
```

I am unsure where I am going wrong? Could this possibly be a syntax error? When I post to that url in postman, I get all of the data that is needed to run this function and send the email, but I get errors at

```
self._forgotPasswordRouteHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail(uuid, parsedRequest.email, person.name_to_call_user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getRoute(): hapi.IRouteConfiguration {
        const self = this;
        return {
            method: 'POST',
            path: this._config.apiPrefix + 'forgotpassword',
            handler: function(request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) {
                const me = self;
                let parsedRequest: IForgotPasswordDataRequest = null;
                let uuid: string;
                const result = new Promise<string>(function(resolve, reject) {
                    me._validator.validate(request.payload, ForgotPasswordDataRequestValidator)
                        .then(function(validationResult) {
                            if (validationResult.error) {
                                resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidRequest));
                                throw null;
                            }
                            parsedRequest = <IForgotPasswordDataRequest> request.payload;
                            return self._forgotPasswordQueries.createEmailResetToken(parsedRequest.email);
                        }
                        , function(error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidRequest));
                            throw null;
                        })
                        .then(function(newUuid: string) {
                            uuid = newUuid;
                            return me._peopleQueries.getPersonByEmail(parsedRequest.email);
                        })
                        .then(function(person: IPersonModel) {
                            resolve(responseHelper.getSuccessResponse(null, null));
                            me._forgotPasswordRouteHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail(uuid, parsedRequest.email, person.name_to_call_user);
                        })
                        .catch(function(error: any) {
                            console.error(error);
                            resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.unknownError));
                        });
                });
                reply(result);
            }
        };
```

You have nested closures (That's why I declared a new `me` variable in the handler, the anonymous functions in the handler does not have the same scope as the handler). Try to avoid this structure.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and that makes sense to control the scope that the anonymous functions have :) But I still get the same, is not a function error.

Comment: I had a problem in my bindings, where I binded the wrong route to the helper

Comment: Yes, running, but the above also fixed a later issue